# Starcraft II Galaxy Editor - How do I decide the dimensions of my dialog?

Tags: starcraft-2, galaxy-editor

How do I decide the dimensions of my dialogs in the Starcraft II Galaxy Editor? I've tried the [Galaxy ++ Editor](http://www.sc2mapster.com/forums/resources/third-party-tools/19619-galaxy-editor/#posts), but it does not seem very accurate and when I use the numbers that they provided me with, the dialog seems really messed up.

Is there a better way for me to decide the width, offset, height, etc. of my dialogs?

Comment: Have you seen this [tutorial](http://starcraft-2-galaxy-editor-tutorials.thehelper.net/tutorials.php?view=166817)?

Comment: @Raidri Yes I have, but I have no idea where they got the dimensions of the dialogs from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dimensions should scale to the current user's resolution (which can be really any user with any resolution).

External libraries similar to [this one](http://www.sc2mapster.com/forums/resources/trigger-libraries/17101-library-get-resolution/) should help you on finding out the current client resolution and scaling your dialogs accordingly.

My advice is, test your dialog in a commonly used resolution and set a ratio accordingly.
For example: Resolution is `1920 x 1080` and dialog looks fine as `600 x 300` box.
Staying true to the X axis, for another client with `1280x800` resolution (lower tier laptop), your dialog should scale to 400 x 200 (ratio is 1280/1920, which is 2/3).

If you happen to show a rather large dialog and you encounter a mismatch, such as your Y dimension is out of bounds on the smaller screen according to calculated ratio, then use the maximum available vertical pixels and scale X accordingly.